# The best solution to make jQuery selectors and functions available globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I got the the problem that I would like to make some selectors and functions available globally throughout my application.

```
var $dragzone = $(".upload-drop-zone");
var $uploadOutput = $('#upload-output');
var $createNoteView = $('#createNoteView');
var $form = $("#note-form");

jQuery.fn.tagName = function () {
    return this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase();;
};
```

Is there any recommended way to so without polluting the global namespace? I was thinking about putting them together into an object but that seems quite verbose to me.

Comment: put them in a seperate global.js file and include that with each page

Comment: Given a reasonable architecture, I can't think of a reason why this would be necessary.  Better to use proper encapsulation and make the modules/services available via requirejs.